# help on a vim search / replace complex regular expression

Tags: regex, vim

Here's what I'd like to do with a regular expression: 2 steps:

(1) transform all variables *in a selected area* like this:

```
$Sejour_deb_mois
$Info_pays
```

to :

```
$SejourDebMois
$InfoPays
```

(2) transform all variables *in a selected area* like this:

```
$this->Sejour_deb_mois
$this->Info_pays
```

to :

```
$this->SejourDebMois
$this->InfoPays
```

And I'm pretty sure this can be done using a regular expression... but I can't figure out the two good ones that do the job...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Olivier Pons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For both of the examples above, this should do the job:

```
s/\(_\)\(.\)/\u\2/g
```

Basically, it's finding every underscore and the following character, grouping them with the parens.  Then, it discards the underscore and uppercases the one character.

If you've visually selected the region and pressed `:`, the whole expression will look like:

```
:'<,'>s/\(_\)\(.\)/\u\2/g
```

Comment: You'll need a : in front of the first example;  Very good answer.

Comment: This doen't work for all, because here's the problem : $this->Nom = mb_ereg_replace("[\\,\",/]","",stripslashes(strtoupper($this->Nom)));

changes mb_ereg_replace to mbEregReplace